# Async fetch with timeout for every request in loop

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, fetch

I have a list of domains. Need to get response status for all domains asynchronously.
(but make a timeout for each request of 3 seconds, so that in case of a long answer, skip it and move on).

But the problem is that the timeout is triggered in general, not on every request and after 3 seconds all responses fail with a "timeout" error. Are there any options how to solve this issue?

```
import mysql from 'mysql2';
import 'dotenv/config';
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
});

const sqlQuery = 'SELECT `domain` FROM `domains` LIMIT 1000';
connection.query(sqlQuery, function (error, results) {
    results.forEach(async(result) => {
        let domainName = 'https://' + result.domain;
        getDomain(domainName);
    });
});

function fetchPromise(url, options, timeout = 3000) {
    return Promise.race([
        fetch(url, options),
        new Promise((_, reject) =>
            setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('timeout')), timeout)
        )
    ]);
}

function getDomain(domain) {
    fetchPromise(domain, {
        method: 'get',
    }, 3000).then(resp => {
        console.log(domain + ' - ' + resp.status);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(domain + ' - ' + error.message);
    }); 
}

connection.end();
```

Comment: Your code looks good at a first glance and it should do what you're expecting. You're firing off all requests simultaneously so they will timeout at the same time as well. Which would make you think the timeout is general, when it's in fact on a per request basis

Comment: When 3 seconds pass, all subsequent domains timeout